# "Menu link plugin with ID 'standard.front_page' does not support deletion"

Tags: 8, navigation

This question is related to two issues on drupal.org:

- [Standard profile: make "Home" menu link to  editable/deletable](https://www.drupal.org/node/2838106)
- [Orphaned menu items should support removeDefinition](https://www.drupal.org/node/2847653)

**Summary**

How to delete a menu item that was defined in `example.links.menu.yml` and then changed, for example by disabling it or changing its weight.

**Steps to reproduce**

- Install a clean Drupal 8 with the Standard installation profile
- Go to `admin/structure/menu/manage/main` and disable the `Home` menu item. This change will write the menu item to `core.menu.static_menu_link_overrides`.
- Delete file `core/profiles/standard/standard.links.menu.yml`
- Clear cache
- Try to delete the now orphaned menu item:

  ```
  $home_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');
  $home_manager->removeDefinition('standard.front_page');
  ```

**Expected behavior**

We are able to delete the menu item.

**Actual behavior**

We get the following error:

> Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginException: "Menu link plugin
>   with ID 'standard.front_page' does not support deletion".

**Question**

Is this a bug in Drupal core, or am I using the wrong way to delete the menu item?

Comment: **Steps to reproduce** `Delete file core/profiles/standard/standard.links.menu.yml` ummmm... core files should never be deleted.

Comment: Cfr issue on d.o [make "Home" menu link to editable/deletable](https://www.drupal.org/node/2838106). We're trying to get rid of `standard.links.menu.yml` and we need an upgrade path. This also works with any other link created in an `example.links.menu.yml` file.

Comment: You seem to have reported it as a bug so the answer is "yes" isn't it?

Comment: I want to know if it is actually a bug, or if I'm missing something. I want to be prepared for core mentoring hour next week.

Comment: @WimMostrey There is nothing that that would require you to delete a core file. You're basically hacking core at this point. There is a rule of thumb that you never touch core.

Comment: I agree with you. However if you check the first d.o link, you'll see that we're actually refactoring the standard module that comes with Drupal core.